# Exception in thread "management-client-thread 1-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space running an Arquillian test on a managed JBoss7.1.1Final

Tags: junit, jboss7.x, out-of-memory, jboss-arquillian

I'm getting the exception above while running a JUnit/Arquillian test in Eclipse Juno having a @Deployment method like this:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment() throws Exception {

    File[] libs = Maven.resolver()
            .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml")
            .importRuntimeDependencies()
            .as(File.class);

    WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
            .addClass(Permission.class)
            .addClass(PermissionInterface.class)
            .addClass(PermissionModel.class)
            .addClass(PermissionModelInterface.class)
            ...
            .addAsLibraries(libs)
            .addAsResource(
                    "resources-jbossas-managed/test-persistence.xml",
                    "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebResource(
                    EmptyAsset.INSTANCE,
                    ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));

    System.out.println(war.toString(true));

    return war;
}
```

and a persistence unit described like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="talmudDatabaseTest">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/Alpha2Test</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss" />
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="True" />
            <property name="eclipselink.session-event-listener" value="it.cnr.ilc.omega.model.PersistenceEventListener" />
            <property name="omega.import-sql" value="false" />
            <property name="omega.import-sql.postlogin-filename" value="preconstruct.sql" />
            <property name="omega.import-sql.postcreate-filename" value="postconstruct.sql" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The running JBoss 7.1.1 Final instance has been launched with this configuration (on a Macbook Pro):

```
-server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/local/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/log/boot.log" "-Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/local/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/logging.properties" "-Djboss.home.dir=/usr/local/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final" "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" "-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=com.apple.laf,com.apple.laf.resources"
```

The @Test method isn't even called... the exception is thrown before it, but after the completion of the @Deployment method. Shrinkwrap creates this web archive:

```
test.war:
/beans.xml
/WEB-INF/
/WEB-INF/lib/
/WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-compat-tomcat-1.1.0.beta3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.0.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.0.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.1.2.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven-2.0.0-beta-3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-resolver-api-2.0.0-beta-3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.9.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-spi-1.1.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-model-builder-3.0.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-plugin-api-2.0.9.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/poi-3.7.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/bcmail-jdk14-138.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-http-shared4-2.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk14-138.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-profile-2.0.9.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/aether-util-1.13.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-compat-jbossweb-1.1.0.beta3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.0.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-2.0.0-beta-3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/itext-2.1.7.js1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/annotation-detector-3.0.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-20041127.091804.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-compat-tomcat7-1.1.0.beta3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-2.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/el-api-2.2.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jdtcore-3.1.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commonj.sdo-2.1.1.v201112051852.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-2.0.0-beta-3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin-1.0.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/aether-spi-1.13.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/aether-impl-1.13.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jcommon-1.0.15.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-provider-api-2.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-compiler-javac-2.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-api-1.1.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-2.0.0-beta-3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jsoup-1.6.3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-33.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-project-2.0.9.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-archive-2.0.0-beta-3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/httpcore-4.2.3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.0.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-resolver-api-maven-archive-2.0.0-beta-3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-artifact-2.0.9.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/poi-ooxml-3.7.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-http-lightweight-2.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jena-core-2.10.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/eclipselink-2.4.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/aether-connector-wagon-1.13.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/castor-1.2.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.0.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jasperreports-fonts-4.0.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/shrinkwrap-resolver-spi-maven-archive-2.0.0-beta-3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jena-tdb-0.10.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.9.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-settings-3.0.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jena-arq-2.10.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/httpclient-4.2.3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/javax.persistence-2.0.4.v201112161009.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/aether-api-1.13.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/maven-model-3.0.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-runtime-1.1.0.beta3.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/plexus-compiler-api-2.1.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jena-iri-0.9.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.0.5.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/jasperreports-5.0.0.jar
/WEB-INF/lib/wagon-file-2.4.jar
/WEB-INF/classes/
/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/
/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
/WEB-INF/classes/it/
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/resources/
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/resources/model/
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/resources/model/SourceInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/resources/model/Source.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/resources/model/AttachmentInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/resources/model/ResourceType.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/resources/model/ResourceInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/resources/model/Resource.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/resources/model/Attachment.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/resources/model/ResourceTypeInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/LoginViewController.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/LoginViewControllerInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/Task.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/Role.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/Credentials.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/PermissionModel.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/TaskInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/UserInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/UserModelInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/TaskModelInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/PermissionInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/PermissionModelInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/User.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/LogoutEvent.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/TaskModel.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/Permission.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/access/model/UserModel.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/model/
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/model/AbstractEntityModel.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/model/AbstractEntityInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/model/EntityDeleteEvent.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/model/EntityCreateEvent.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/model/EntityUpdateEvent.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/model/AbstractEntityModelInterface.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/model/AbstractEntity$Status.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/model/PersistenceEventListener.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/model/AbstractEntity.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/BaseController.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/Resources.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/reference/
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/reference/model/
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/reference/model/Reference.class
/WEB-INF/classes/it/cnr/ilc/omega/reference/model/ReferenceInterface.class
```

After that, Arquillian adds the archive on the active instance of JBoss, but the deployment can't terminate its operations. I've also managed to raise the memory for the JVM, but it doesn't seem to work. If I remove the libs form the archive, the @Test method is passed correctly, but the Session bean i'd like to inject:

```
@Inject
LoginViewController loginViewController;
```

isn't resolved like it should.

Can anyone help to find why the exception occurs? Thanks in advance... any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you're using a remote server deployment or a managed server deployment with Arquillian?

Comment: It's a managed server... I'm running the test in an active instance (set in arquillian.xml). Also, I've even modified the JBoss's standalone.xml trying to manage memory related JVM parameters there, but nothing changed... the exception is always thrown.

Comment: Problem solved: the Arquillian/JUnit test is run in a different JVM, so that to correctly pass the parameters to this other JVM one needs to create a new JUnit run configuration in the appropriate Eclipse panel under the "arguments" tab. Hope this can help someone. Bye!

Comment: To complete the test, I've noticed that the beans.xml has to be put inside the WEB-INF directory so if you look at my code, change the ArchivePaths parameter to: WEB_INF/beans.xml. Bye!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.addAsWebResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));

should be

.addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"));